# Flutter - No breaking words into newline at hyphen in Text

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I stop breaking word into newline at hyphen character. Here is the relevant code

```dart
Container(
  color: Colors.red.withOpacity(.4),
  width: 315,
  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
    horizontal: 12.0,
    vertical: 6.0,
  ),
  child: Text(
    'Ultra Low-Fat',
    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
  ),
)
```

Currently the screen looks like this

[image]

But I want the text to show like this

```
Ultra
Low-Fat
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I managed to solve this by replacing all hyphens with [non-breaking hyphen](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2011/index.htm) character `\u2011`

```dart
const nonBreakingHyphen = '\u2011';

...

Text(
  // text will now not break at hyphen
  title.replaceAll('-', nonBreakingHyphen),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
child:Column(
    children:<widgets>(
         Row(
            children:<widgets>(
                Text("Ultra", //your theme)),
         Row(
            children:<widgets>(
                Text("Low-Fat", //your theme)
            )
        )
    )
```

Comment: That layout is overkill for such simple task. I can just use `Text('Ultra\nLow-Fat')` but I want to insert newline dynamically depend on different paragraph lengths. I don't want to hardcode multiple strings together

Comment: You can use **wrap** then. Look out for wrap.